# Interpreters vs Compilers vs Virtual Machines

Tags: compiler-construction, vm-implementation

I have a question about Interpreters, Compilers, and Virtual Machines (VMs).

Now I know the differences between Interpreters and Compilers but what is different about the **VIRTUAL MACHINES** from the previous 2? What are the Pros and Cons of a VM over Interpreters and Compilers?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A virtual machine isn't exactly an alternative to compilers or interpreters. I think you are thinking of a JIT compiler, which is how many VMs are implemented.

A virtual machine itself is exactly what the name says - it's a machine (processor) that doesn't actually exist. For example, most processors don't have any intrinsic way of dealing with memory allocation, or any knowledge of types. The Java VM though, has a `new` instruction that allocates an instance of a certain class. The designers of the VM decided that this was an important enough concept in the language to deserve its own opcode, which is the fundamental unit of operation in the VM.

The advantages of creating your own instruction set are generally to bridge the gap between long compile/optimization times and slow interpreters. When you compile a Java class, for example, you don't have to do any register allocation or inlining or any of that traditional compiler stuff. The JIT will do that later, but only for the parts of code that you run enough times, and spread out over the run of the program. The JVM's instruction set is close enough to Java that the initial compile is quick, and it is simple and quick to read for the VM, unlike Java source code.

As for interpreters vs JIT compilers, the tradeoffs are generally around runtime performance vs development time. A JIT takes a lot longer to develop, but an interpreter is a lot slower while running. In a lot of cases though, like scripting and small to medium sized websites, the program doesn't run long enough for you to really see any benefits of using a JIT.

I should also mention software like VMware. This is also a virtual machine, but it uses an instruction set that also happens to be used on real hardware. It's the same basic concept as a language VM, in that it pretends to be a machine that isn't physically present, but in practice it's different and very complicated.

Comment: Top Notch Mate, just what I needed

Comment: "doesn't actuallly exist" isn't exactly the proper expression. What is true is that there might not be a manufactured machine processor that can consume the same bytecode language of a given VM. It doesn't mean that such a machine processor can not be manufactured.

Answer (score 25):

Plain English

**Compiler** transforms one language into another. For example, C# into IL, Java into byte code, C++ into binary machine code. No execution happens at the compilation stage.

**Interpreter** interprets (executes) one line at a time from the source file. Such as PHP, Perl, other scripting languages

**Virtual Machine** can refer to several things, the two I am aware of:

- Hypervisor-related virtual machine, such as [Hyper-V](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V), [Xen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xen). These allow you to run several OS on a single piece of hardware
- Software run time, like [Java Virtual Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine), [Common Language Runtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime). This piece of software allow one to run platform independent intermediate language (IL code, byte code) and execute machine-specific instructions ([just-in-time compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation)). Usually, such VM is responsible for other satellite tasks: resource management, memory clean up, threading, security etc

There are no pros and cons. All three do different jobs that can hardly be compared.

<sub>Languages and platforms come in no particular order, there are literally hundreds of other samples</sub>

Comment: Compiler & Interpreter & VM can be written for any languages and any language can be translated into a form that can be executed by a descent VM. Any language can be compiled and of course any language can be interpreted. That doesn't mean that it's interesting thing to do.

Answer (score 6):

## Real Machines vs Virtual Machines

- Real machine is one whose machine code is executed by hardware
- Virtual machine is one whose "machine code" is executed by an interpreter.

## Interpreters vs Compilers

[**Answer is here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23456402/3300831)

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but I think I can add value. Traditionally, a compiler or interpreter translated a high-level language into the machine language that ran on the target computer.

Prior to virtual-machines (VMs), a unique compiler or interpreter was required for any pair of high-level language and target machine language. This led to compilers and interpreters that depended on every detail of both the high-level language and the target computer's machine language.

By breaking the translation of the high-level language to machine language into two-steps in two separate programs, we break this dependency.

The first program translates the high-level language to an intermediate code. In Java this is called bytecode. The first program is still known as a compiler.

The second program translates this intermediate code into the machine language of the target computer.

The conceptual system that runs the intermediate code is called a virtual-machine.

The same compiler can now be used for any computer for which a VM exists that accepts the intermediate code produced by the compiler.

Compilers for some languages share the same VM which enables routines from one language to easily call routines in another language sharing the same VM.

A full explanation of VMs and guided exercises in creating your own VM can be found in the book 'The elements of computing systems' by Noam Nisan and Shimon Schoken.