# Don't understand pre decrement operator behavior with Nullable type

Tags: c#, nullable

Ok, this might be obvious for some of you but I am stumped with the behavior I'm getting from this rather simple code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int? n = 1;
    int i = 1;
    n = ++n - --i;
    Console.WriteLine("Without Nullable<int> n = {0}", n); //outputs n = 2

    n = 1;
    i = 1;
    n = ++n - new Nullable<int>(--i);
    Console.WriteLine("With Nullable<int> n = {0}", n); //outputs n = 3
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I exepcted both outputs to be the same and equal to `2` but strangely enough they aren't. Can someone explain why?

**EDIT:** Although the code to generate this "weird" behavior is admittedly contrived, it does look like a bug in the C# compiler though seemingly unimportant and the reason seems to be the inlined `new` as [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82586/james) pointed out initially. But the behavior is not limited to operations. Method calls behave exactly the same way, that is, they are called twice when they should only be called once.

Consider the following repro:

```
public static void Main()
    {
        int? n = 1;
        int i = 1;
        n = n - new Nullable<int>(sideEffect(ref i));
        Console.WriteLine("With Nullable<int> n = {0}", n);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static int sideEffect(ref int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("sideEffect({0}) called", i);
        return --i;
    }
```

Sure enough, output is `2` when it should be `1` and `"sideEffect(i) called"` is printed out twice.

Comment: This is something to do with the fact the `new Nullable<int>(--i)` is inline because if you assign it to a variable *then* do the operation it's fine. What's also odd is if I put a breakpoint on that line and then put in the watch `new Nullable<int>(--i)` it decrements `i` (which makes sense) but *increments* the final result by the same number :s

Comment: @James: Wierd...this doesn't seem to be a desirable behavior...

Comment: well from where I am standing I would say no, or at least not what I would expect to happen. I would expect a new nullable variable to be created on the fly which equals 0.

Comment: ReSharper actually suggests "Remove redundant 'new'", which turns the second one into the first (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-49302)

Comment: `n = ++n - new Nullable<int>(i--);` results in `n` being `2` when it should be `1`, so it doesn't appear to be exclusively a problem with the predecrement operator; the postdecrement also acts up.

Comment: also, `i = i - 1` evaluates twice, too.

Comment: So the bug is that the compiler is executing that statement twice, whatever it is.

Comment: Its because if you put "--" before the variable the value is passed as its original value then decremented after the value has been past.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wc3z3k8c(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Rene147: huh? pre decrement is named "pre" because it does precisely the contrary. Your behavior is what the "post" decrement operator would do.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**EDIT:** This has been confirmed as a bug in the compiler by the team. It is fixed in Roslyn. As a workaround, use a cast `(int?)(--i)` to stop the bug appearing, or don't explicitly cast it to a `Nullable<int>` in the first place.

The first code block generates the following in reflector:

```
int? nullable3;
int? nullable = 1;
int num = 1;
int? nullable2 = nullable;
nullable2 = nullable = nullable2.HasValue
    ? new int?(nullable2.GetValueOrDefault() + 1)    
   : ((int?) (nullable3 = null));
int num2 = --num;
nullable = nullable2.HasValue
    ? new int?(nullable2.GetValueOrDefault() - num2)
    : ((int?) (nullable3 = null));
Console.WriteLine("Without Nullable<int> n = {0}", nullable);
```

The second the following:

```
nullable = 1;
num = 1;
nullable2 = nullable;
nullable2 = nullable = nullable2.HasValue
    ? new int?(nullable2.GetValueOrDefault() + 1)
    : ((int?) (nullable3 = null));
num2 = --num;
nullable = nullable2.HasValue
    ? new int?(nullable2.GetValueOrDefault() - --num)
    : null;
Console.WriteLine("With Nullable<int> n = {0}", nullable);
```

They're more or less the same, up to the assignment to `nullable`. It's running `--num` twice, causing it to run `2 - -1`, resulting in 3.

It also does the same with expressions like `i = ~i`, but not with method call expressions...

Comment: I tried method calls, but couldn't get it to reproduce. It was with a no-args method though rather than a ref argument, maybe that's got something to do with it?

Comment: Not sure and I can't check it out now.  About the `ref`, its not part of the problem. I put it in only to make *visble* that the final value of `n` is incorrect. If I didn't pass `i` by reference, even if you call `sideEffects(i)` twice, `i` at the callsite will only be decremented once and the code apparently works fine. Its obvious that is not the case as `sideEffect(i) called` is printed twice in the console, with or without `ref`.

Comment: You are correct that methods with no arguments behave correctly. Methods with arguments do not, no matter how they are passed.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite an interesting problem, from what I can see the compiler *appears* to evaluate the `--`/`++` statements more than once. For example, the following:

```
n = ++n - new Nullable<int>(i++)
```

results in `n` becoming `0` (which you would expect) but `i` is now `3` (which you would expect to be `2`). However, if I do

```
n = ++n - new Nullable<int>(i);
```

Then I get the expected result (`n` = `1` and `i` = `1`)

I can only assume this is *somehow* related to the `new Nullable` call being in-line. I don't really see this as being much of an issue as this probably wouldn't be considered your everyday sort of code, however, in my opinion it does appear to be a bug with the compiler.

Comment: My cshtml example does not use a compiler so it can't be the compiler

Comment: @ThomasFonseca so how does it run the C# code on the computer without a compiler?

Comment: @ThomasFonseca your cshtml *does* use a compiler, the ASP.NET one.

Comment: @James it uses an interpreter not a compiler(or maybe a little of both) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377273/how-does-an-interpreter-compiler-work

Comment: @Coop see my comment to james above regarding the difference between an interpreter and a compiler.

Comment: @ThomasFonseca: Wrong. Razor pages use the same C# compiler that normal C# files use.  For more detail, see my blog.  http://blog.slaks.net/2011/02/dissecting-razor-part-4-anatomy-of.html/

Answer (score -2):

Well its most odd, I've tried to track down the actual code off '--' but I'm unable to but if you do

```
            n = 1;
        i = 1;
        n = ++n - new Nullable<int>(i--);
        Console.WriteLine("With Nullable<int> n = {0}", n); //outputs n = 2
        Console.ReadKey();
```

It outputs as expected.

edit: All is revealed:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wc3z3k8c(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: The expected value of `n = ++n - new Nullable<int>(i--);` is 1, not 2.

Comment: No, you are getting the wrong output of 2: If you use the postdecrement, then the correct output should be `1`. And the link, I'm sorry to say, doesn't help your case all that much ;)

Comment: Sorry you are correct, getting my prefix and postfix the wrong way round :(

Answer (score -3):

It is because on this line:

```
  n = ++n - new Nullable<int>(--i);
```

i becomes -1 and 2 - (-1) = 3;

The reason it becomes negative 1 is that you are newing a nulluable object that is initialized to 0 and then subtracting one (i).

you can run this code as a *.cshtml file in your browser:

```
@{

    int? m = 1;
    int i = 1;
    m = ++m - --i;
    //MessageBox.Show("Without Nullable<int> n = {0}", n); //outputs n = 2

    int? n = 1;
    i = 1;
    n = ++n - new Nullable<int>(--i);
    //MessageBox.Show("With Nullable<int> n = {0}", n); //outputs n = 3

}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>m = @m</h2>
    <h2>n = @n</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well that's a wierd way to look at the issue. I'm predecrementing the *argument* of the `Nullable<int>` constructor, I'm most definitely not decrementing the `Nullable<int>`. What I expected would happen is that `--i` returned `0` and `new Nullable<int>(0)` resolved to `0`. Evidently that does not happen.

Comment: I did not say you were subtracting one from the nullable object - I said you are subtracting one from the initializer, in this case i.

Comment: @SLaks - you are correct my bad. http://bubblogging.wordpress.com/2012/01/09/mvc-razor-view/