# How nodejs interpreter is interpreting javascript in to cpp

Tags: node.js, interpreter, expert-advisor

In [NodeJs project](https://github.com/nodejs/node)
**Lib**:
Lib folder is a bunch of functions written in Javascript, built-in modules

**Src**
Src folder is some of cpp programme, which is the core of nodejs.

Now, my question is, how nodejs is running, how it connecting js lib with src and what the other folders works!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does an interpreter/compiler work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377273/how-does-an-interpreter-compiler-work)

Comment: Nodejs has a programming interface that allows C++ code to publish an interface that is available to Javascript and then when Javascript calls it, that code in the interface transforms Javascript data/variables into the C++ world (where it can be used by the C++ code) and then vice versa for any data being returned back to Javascript.  This is used by both the internal C++ implementation of nodejs (for features that are implemented in C++) and can be used by your own add-ons (things you write in C++ and create an interface for them to be called from Javascript).

Comment: Many parts of the internals of nodejs are implemented in C++.  For example, the whole nodejs event loop is implemented in libuv in C++.  File I/O is implemented in C++ and so on...

Comment: @Konrad no, I'm asking the internal flow of nodejs, not how it's works.